# Can someone explain why my MySQL table data is not being displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7.2

I'm new to PHP and MySQL. I have an HTML table and form that submits the entered data to MySQL, but doesn't display the MySQL data in my HTML table. Here is an image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9k8K.png. I want the submitted data to display upon submission if possible but am unable to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$host    = "localhost";
$user    = "root";
$pass    = "";
$db = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

if(isset($_POST["asin"]))
{
    $asin =  $_POST["asin"];
    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $submit = "INSERT INTO `user_input`(`id`, `asin`, `category`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$asin', '$category', CURRENT_DATE())";

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $submit);
    if (!$sql) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    $display = "SELECT * FROM user_input";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $display);
    if (!$result) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>testEnv</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
form {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

table, thead, tbody, th, td {
    padding: 4px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

form {
    font-size: 13px;
}

th, td {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="form" method="post">
            <div>
            <label id="asinLabel" for="asin">ASIN:</label>
            <input id="asinInput" type="text" name="asin"></input>
            <label id="categoryLabel" for="category">Category:</label>
            <input id="categoryInput" type="text" name="category"></input>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="container-fluid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>ASIN</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>6:00 AM</th>
                    <th>8:00 AM</th>
                    <th>10:00 AM</th>
                    <th>12:00 PM</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
                <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
                {  
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['asin'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['category'].'</td>
                            <td>'. date('m d, Y', strtotime($row['date'])) .'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['6am'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['8am'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['10am'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['12pm'].'</td>
                        </tr>';
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script rel="script" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script rel="script" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script rel="script" type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd suppose that you only need to move the block outside the `if(isset($_POST["asin"]))` sentence

Comment: Just tried, Unfortunately no luck.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can be sloppy, that you can half-ass it. Doing it properly *saves time* because you'll never battle bugs that could have been avoided by not cutting corners in the first place. Plus, this is private today. What if some day in the near future the tool becomes really successful and it gets pushed to the public without your knowledge? These things happen. This is code that's inherently dangerous no matter how it's contained.

Comment: Even so, you should be careful and try to make things as safe as possible. This code just can be useful to learn how this works but putting something like this to the world is an opportunity for a needless disaster.

Comment: I did what you said, @RiggsFolly and it states that '$asin =  $_POST["asin"]; $category = $_POST["category"];' are undefined variables.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. @tadman.

Comment: If your `$_POST` values are undefined, check that your form is actually submitted with POST. You can look in your Network inspector on your browser to see what happened, plus your server logs.

Comment: I agree. I just have to get this done quickly with minimal knowledge. @MikeVelazco. I can improve upon its security once it functions and the company can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write

```
 $display = "SELECT * FROM user_input";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $display);
    if (!$result) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

block out side of the condition.